# Node cron send mail after 10 minutes

Tags: node.js, cron

What I want to achieve here is when I enter the post route, I want to send email after 10 minutes. For that I'm using `node-cron`. But this schedule doesnt send the mail after 10 minutes. I believe this sets it up when the minute itself is at 10 then the mail is sent ? How can I achieve that when I enter the route the mail is sent after 10 minutes one time ?

```
        cron.schedule("10 * * * *", function(){
            const mailOptions = {
                from: 'example@gmail.com', // sender address
                to: 'example@gmail.com', // list of receivers
                subject: 'Test | ' + newadvertisement.manufacturer + ' ' + newadvertisement.brand, // Subject line
                html: '<p>Test
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err)
                else
                    console.log(info);
            });
        });
```

P.S my code works without node-cron. Also I get no errors.

Comment: Why not using setTimeout ?

Comment: @Avihaym Do you think it's a good method ?

Comment: Sure...you dont need cron.

Comment: But I also have six user groups. And for every user group the same email have to be sent. For first group after 10 min, for second group after 20 min. etc. Is six setTimeouts is still reliable ? @Avihaym

Comment: You can set the time as variable and change it according to the group.

Comment: As mentioned below, cron is not what you are looking for, if you are only looking to send the mail once. Also for `setTimeout()`: It is a viable solution, but be aware that if your server stops or crashes for any reason during the timeout, the mails will **not** be sent.

Comment: @Enslev OK I'll use the setTimeout. If the mail once be wont sent that not a big problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is how cron works. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for more reading.
TL;DR: It will, as you said, send the mail **every** time the time is 10 minutes past the hour, and not just once.

For what you want you could do a simple [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with a 600000 delay (1000ms * 60sec * 10min).

Or you could use [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda) for much more control on when it acts. This requires some sort of database, but it is more reliable since `setTimeout()` will not work if the server is restarted after the timeout is set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe right now it's sending every hour, for eternity, whenever the minute = 10

If you want to use cron for this, you'll need to set a value instead of those asterixes:

`cron.schedule("40 16 28 Feb Thu",`

However if it's a one time action, you can use timeouts instead.

```
setTimeout(sendEmail(),600000);
```